# ng-bootstrap modal open on ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I want to open the modal from my typescript code, that is when the component loads on the ngOnit() the modal popup should open , I don't want to create a button on the html file.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2 mr-2" (click)="openSm(content)">Small modal</button>

<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="modal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Ts:

```
openSm(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, { size: 'sm' });
  }
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wk98yf?file=src/app/modal-options.ts)

I want to open the modal on ngOnit() function.

Comment: Hi, the attached StackBlitz link was broken.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

please find this link to get stackblitz link

Comment: @YongShun updated the stackblitz link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use ViewChild to get the "content" and in ngOnInit call to this.open(this.content)

```
  @ViewChild("content",{static:true}) content:ElementRef;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.openSm(this.content)
  }
```

your forked [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpwuaj?file=src/app/modal-options.ts)

NOTE: I use `{static:true}` and put the code in ngOnInit because I imagine your "content" is always "visible", else you need use ngAfterViewInit

Comment: thank you very much it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewchild and afterviewinit lifehook.

```
 @ViewChild("content") modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;


  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.modalService.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'sm' });
}
```